# The namespace ''..." already contains a definition for

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is my code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
 
public class NodeEditor : EditorWindow
{
   [MenuItem("Editors/Node Editor")]
   private static void Init ()
   {
       EditorWindow w = EditorWindow.GetWindow(typeof(NodeEditor), true,"Node Editor");
       w.Show ();
   }    
 
   private void OnGUI ()
   {
       SetupHeader ();
       NodeLoop ();
       Repaint ();
   }
 
    private void SetupHeader ()
    {
        Rect header = r (0, 0, width, 90);
        GUI.Box (header, "");
 
        Rect placeNode = o (header, 20, 5, 100, 20);
        if (GUI.Button(placeNode, "Place Node"));
        {
 
        }
    }
 
   private void NodeLoop()
   {
 
   }
 
    private float width
    {
        get
        {
            return Screen.width;
        }
    }
 
    private float height
    {
        get
        {
            return Screen.height;
        }
    }
 
    private Rect r (float xPos, float yPos, float xSize, float ySize)
    {
        return new Rect (new Vector2(xPos,yPos), new Vector2(xSize,ySize));
    }
 
    private Rect o (Rect r,float xOff, float yOff, float xSize, float ySize)
    {
        return new Rect (new Vector2(r.position.x + xOff, r.position.y + yOff), new Vector2(xSize,ySize));
    }




}
```

and here are my errors,

> Assets\Node Editor\Editor\NodeEditor.cs(6,14): error CS0101: The
> namespace '' already contains a definition for
> 'NodeEditor' Assets\Node Editor\Editor\NodeEditor.cs(9,24): error
> CS0111: Type 'NodeEditor' already defines a member called 'Init' with
> the same parameter types Assets\Node
> Editor\Editor\NodeEditor.cs(15,17): error CS0111: Type 'NodeEditor'
> already defines a member called 'OnGUI' with the same parameter types

Comment: Can you please try to add a namespace in your file: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/namespaces

Comment: Unity doesn’t enforce namespaces and puts everything in a default one. Odds are that you’ve five the same method signature multiple times. So either wrap the class in a namespace or rename some of the methods

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the class in a namespace. Namespaces are basically containers for classes

Comment: Im not sure i understand how to do that. may you please elaborate?

Comment: Just use this link and look at the code snippets:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/namespaces